# Recommended F-Stop for older Canon 35mm F/2

Tags: lens, canon, image-quality, optics, f-stop

I have a few year old Canon 35mm F/2 lens ([Here it is on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009XVCU)). I've been shooting wide-open, but I realize that doesn't make for the sharpest photos. What would you say would get me the sharpest photos without bringing the f-stop down too low?

Answer (score 0):

"Too low" is a very subjective term, but for using the lens on both [a crop camera](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/lens-compare?lensId=canon_35_2p0&cameraId=canon_eos7d&version=0&fl=35&av=8&view=mtf-ca) and on [a full frame camera](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/lens-compare?lensId=canon_35_2p0&cameraId=canon_eos5dmkii&version=0&fl=35&av=8&view=mtf-ca), the lens is sharpest in the range of f/4.0 to f/8.0 or so.